# Show Vertical Graph Bar Percentage in the middle of div

Tags: html, css

I have a progress bar that I need to be able to show the percentage text always in the middle of the progress bar. Currently, only the values are not vertically centered inside the progress bar. I need to do this only with html and CSS and not jQuery or javascript

[image]

```css
.vertical .progress-bar {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.vertical .progress-track {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}
.vertical .progress-fill {
  position: relative;
  height: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical">
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track">
      <div class="progress-fill" style="height: 100%; top: 0%; background: rgb(191, 231, 178);"></div>
      <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">100%</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track">
      <div class="progress-fill" style="height: 80%; top: 20%; background: rgb(248, 231, 153);"></div>
      <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">80%</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track">
      <div class="progress-fill" style="height: 60%; top: 40%; background: rgb(248, 231, 153);"></div>
      <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">60%</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track">
      <div class="progress-fill" style="height: 2%; top: 98%; background: rgb(248, 138, 138);">
        <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">0%</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide proper code snippet so that i can able to see output

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Revised answer below; see Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ybygucn7/

HTML:

```
<div class="vertical">
    <div class="progress-bar">
        <div class="progress-track">
             <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">100%</span>
             <div class="progress-fill" style="height: 100%; background: rgb(191, 231, 178);"></div>   
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.vertical .progress-bar {
  height: 100px;
  width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.progress-bar .progress-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  position: relative;
}

.vertical .progress-fill {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.vertical span {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50%;
    width: inherit;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Based on the updated images it seems we're both wrong and the OP wants the percentages centered based on the wrapper height, rather than the color fill.

Comment: the link I sent is to represent your code solution. I just posted it, so it is easy to visualize

Answer (score 0):

I have made changes in your HTML and in CSS `.progress-bar` overflow has `hidden`, try this.

```css
.vertical .progress-bar {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.vertical .progress-track {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  //overflow:hidden;
}
.vertical .progress-fill {
  position: relative;
  height: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical">
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track">
      <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);top:20%;position:absolute;z-index:1;">100%</span>
      <div class="progress-fill" style="background: rgb(191, 231, 178);height:100px; top:0%;"></div>
         </div>
  </div>

  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track">
      <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);top:20%;position:absolute;z-index:1;">80%</span>
       <div class="progress-fill" style="background: rgb(248, 231, 153);height:80px; top:20%;"></div>
       </div>
  </div>

  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track">
      <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);top:40%;position:absolute;z-index:1;">60%</span>
   <div class="progress-fill" style="background: rgb(248, 231, 153);height:60px; top:40%;"></div>
   
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track">
        <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);top:40%;position:absolute;z-index:1;">0%</span>
<div class="progress-fill" style="background: rgb(248, 138, 138);height:5px; top:95%;">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can we add text underneath each bar. i.e date like 5/13 or any type of text?

Comment: @AhmedMahmoud well this works perfect for you, isn't it. And you can't add it into this as we have used overflow:hidden.

Comment: @AhmedMahmoud you need to add another span tag and then adjust it's top position, but date will be visible inside bar.

Comment: currently it works as expected, but I still need a way to show some text underneath each bar :)
any suggestions?

Comment: @AhmedMahmoud add another span tag below progress-fill and remove overflow:hidden from .progress-bar and add your span tag date <span style="top:100%;position:absolute;z-index:9;">5/13</span>